# proving that f is bijection from NxNxN to N

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

How should I construct a function to show that their exist a bijection from $\mathbb {N}$x$\mathbb {N}$x$\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Start by taking your favorite bijection $g:\mathbb N\times\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ (see several of the "Related" links to the right), and then let $f(x,y,z)=g(x,g(y,z))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the sequence of all positive integers coprime with $6$:
$$\{a_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}=\{1, 5,7,11,13,17,19,23,25,\ldots\}$$

Define
$$f(a,b,c)=2^a3^ba_c-1$$

*Remark*:
This assumes that $0\in\Bbb N$. If not, simply define $f(a,b,c)=2^{a-1}3^{b-1}a_c$ instead.

Comment: If $0\in\mathbb N$, then your $f$ doesn't hit it. On the other hand, if $0\notin\mathbb N$ for you, then your $f$ doesn't hit $1$.

Comment: Thanks, I think "zero-issues" are fixed now.