# How to write down a bijection from $\mathbb N$ onto $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations

I'm looking for a bijection from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N\times\mathbb  N\times\mathbb  N$.

- I know it exists
- I know an informal way to define one, ordering the triplets of natural numbers in a 3D array an counting them diagonally as they do [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cartesian_Product_of_Countable_Sets_is_Countable) with 2D array.
- And I know a bijection from $\mathbb N\times\mathbb  N\times\mathbb  N$ to $\mathbb N$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1915728/proving-that-f-is-bijection-from-nxnxn-to-n) which uses factorization

But how to write it explicitly?

Thank you very much.

Comment: "the" inverse? For "a" bijection? You do know there are many bijections, right?

Comment: I know, I just want **a** bijection

Comment: If you have a bijective function $f:\mathbb N\times\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$, then $f^{-1}$ can be defined as follows: $f^{-1}(x) = (a,b,c)$ where $f(a,b,c) = x$. If what you actually want is an efficient algorithm to compute $f^{-1}$, you should ask for that rather than just a definition.

Comment: Yes, I want to write it explicitly and not in terms of its inverse

Comment: A good exercise would be to take the informal argument and process it to the point that you make that one formal as opposed to "fixing" a bijection that is easily formalized..

Comment: $$\pi:(a,b,c)\mapsto \binom{a+b+c+2}{3}+\binom{a+b+1}{2}+\binom{a}{1}$$ is a bijective map between $\mathbb{N}^3$ and $\mathbb{N}$. I leave to you the fun to invert it.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the reason you're not getting the kinds of answers you want for your question is that you're not asking the question whose answer you want. Maybe you should start the next question by giving more context, such as _why_ you need to "write" a bijection. Then you might get some suggestions that actually were useful for your purposes, or perhaps even a better way to accomplish your actual goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Cantor's pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function) $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ twice: $(a,b,c) \mapsto \langle \langle a,b \rangle, c \rangle$. Cantor's pairing function has an inverse which is easily-stated if a bit fiddly (see the proof of bijectivity on the linked Wikipedia page).

Comment: Ok, this answers my question, but now I have another problem. I wanted that bijection  to transform a triple series into a simple one, and I don't know how to put that 'floor function' in an index in order to evaluate the series. Maybe I should post another question...

Comment: Thank you very much anyway

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Can you find an explicit bijection from $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/709925)

Comment: No this doesn't, this provides a hint. Literally the first word.

Comment: Personally I don't think it's enough of a hint to be an answer more so than a comment under the question. It's a fine line of course.

Answer (score 1):

Since you ask for any such bijection, here is one random idea. Note that $\mathbb{N}$ excludes $0$ in following text.

Going from $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ can be done easily by realizing that each natural number can be expressed uniquely as a 
$$n=2^{a_0-1}(2a_1-1).$$
We can go even further and expand $2a_1$ and get unique form expressed as 
$$n=2^{a_0-1}(2^{a_1}(2a_2-1)-1).$$
Actually, this way we can get bijection from $\mathbb{N}^n$ to $\mathbb{N}$.

Now to go reverse, let's just denote $v_2(n)$ to be the exponent of prime $2$ in prime factorization of $n$. Then you can go backwards to get individual $a_i$'s:

\begin{align}
a_0 &= v_2(n)+1 \\
a_1 &= v_2\left(\frac{n}{2^{a_0-1}}+1\right) \\
a_2 &= \frac{\frac{\frac{n}{2^{a_0-1}}+1}{2^{a_1}}+1}{2}\\
\end{align}

Then just sending $n$ to $(a_0, a_1, a_2)$ gives a bijection (because of uniqueness of such expression of each natural number).

First few numbers then map:

\begin{align}
1 = 2^{\color{red}{1}-1}(2^\color{red}{1}(2\cdot \color{red}{1}-1)-1) \to (\color{red}{1},\color{red}{1},\color{red}{1}) \\
2 = 2^{\color{red}{2}-1}(2^\color{red}{1}(2\cdot \color{red}{1}-1)-1) \to (\color{red}{2},\color{red}{1},\color{red}{1}) \\
3 = 2^{\color{red}{1}-1}(2^\color{red}{2}(2\cdot \color{red}{1}-1)-1) \to (\color{red}{1},\color{red}{2},\color{red}{1}) \\
4 = 2^{\color{red}{3}-1}(2^\color{red}{1}(2\cdot \color{red}{1}-1)-1) \to (\color{red}{3},\color{red}{1},\color{red}{1}) \\
5 = 2^{\color{red}{1}-1}(2^\color{red}{1}(2\cdot \color{red}{2}-1)-1) \to (\color{red}{1},\color{red}{1},\color{red}{2}) \\
\end{align}

Comment: Ok, but how do you write $v_2(n)$ explicitly in terms of $n$?

Comment: Well Im not aware of any such formula if that is what you ask, though this itself it is explicit in terms of $v_2(n)$. I guess it all depends on what operations/functions are you allowed to use in the explicit bijection you want. Maybe someone else can add more simple and explicit bijection, in that case consider this as an interesting alternative :)

Comment: As I told @PatrickStevens , I want the bijection  to transform a triple series into a simple one, and I don't know how to put that 'floor function' in an index in order to evaluate the series. But thank you very much anyway